# IP/DNS inaccessible after IP address changed for Wordpress on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: vps, wordpress, apache2, domain-name, ubuntu-20.04

I deployed a website on a VPS with AWS Lightsail. Everything was working fine until I got an issue that made me restart the server. The IP has changed. And now it redirects to the old IP when I get to the new one.

Can anyone tell me where and how I can make that working well again?

I've tried in the database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "https://(...)
```

But I got the message "0 row affected", and it did not change anything...

Thank you so much for your help because it is really mind-boggling and I've been on this issue for a few days, also searched for it online without success.

Comment: Once you get this fixed, allocate a static IP to avoid the problem in future https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-create-static-ip

Comment: Suggest you check the Wordpress console to ensure all references are to domain name rather than IP address. You can also search your database. You may be able to search for a solution to this problem on Google as well.

Comment: Thank you I did this and everything works fine. Now I just have the issue that having 2 websites on the same server, I can't get each Domain pointing to them.

Comment: I have six websites on my server, no issues. That's probably another question to ask though as you'll need to tell us about your software and configuration. Please answer your own question to say how you resolved the problem so others can learn from it :)